# Check if a subset of characters in a list of strings is contained in another list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, combinations

So I have two list of strings. Those strings are formed by a sorted combination of one or more different characters. The characters are not all in the alphabet but are given.

Let's say, all the possible characters are [A, B, C, D, E], then the two lists have a combination of those elements (from 1 up to 5 in this case).

Example:

```
list1 = [AB, AB, C]
list2 = [ABC, CD, ABCDE, E]
```

The number of elements in each list is not defined, but can range from 1 to 30, with the general case being around 10.

Now, what I want is to tell if there is at least one combination of unique characters per string in `list1` that also exists in `list2`, regardless order. In the example, [A, A, C] is contained in `list2` with [A, C, A, E].

The naive way I found to do this is doing all the possible 1 character combinations from each list and see if exists at least one case where `list1` is contained in `list2`. But this can grow exponentially as all possible combinations of a 10 element list of 5-characters strings can be huge (and that's only the general case).

I have thought of using regular expressions or something like that, but I am really not picturing a more efficient solution.

I am using Python for this. Just in case is relevant because of an existing solution or library.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: So for each list you want to build the set of combinations where each element in the combination comes from a separate item in the list? Can an item from the list not contribute to the combination?  (i.e. would `list1` in your example contain `{A, C}`?)

Comment: For the first question yes. The combination is formed by one (and only one) element of each string in the list. I don't understand the second question. I want to find at least one combination from `list1` contained in one combination from `list2`

Answer (score 5):

This may be a prime candidate for set operations. Lets take your example (notice, we needed to add quotes to make them strings).

```
list1 = ["AB", "AB", "C"]
list2 = ["ABC", "CD", "ABCDE", "E"]
```

If we want a set with unique elements from both `list1` and `list2`

```
print(set(list1) | set(list2))
#OUTPUT: {'C', 'AB', 'ABCDE', 'CD', 'ABC', 'E'}
```

If we want to check what elements are common in both `list1` and `list2`(If we were to add "C" to `list2` we would have an output of `{'C'}` otherwise, there are no common elements shared which results in an empty `set()`)

```
print(set(list1) & set(list2)) 
#OUTPUT: set()
```

If we want the elements that are in `list1` but not in `list2`

```
print(set(list1) - set(list2))
#OUTPUT: {'C', 'AB'}
```

If we want a set with elements that are either in `list1` or `list2`

```
print(set(list1) ^ set(list2)) 
#OUTPUT: {'E', 'CD', 'AB', 'ABC', 'C', 'ABCDE'}
```

For more information you can check out https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

I hope this helped!